# undefined reference to '__imp_fmi2_import_free'

Tags: c, linker-errors, static-linking, fmi, jmodelica

I have been trying to compile and link a test file written in c and which can communicate with FMILibrary of JModelica. I was able to compile and link it and run it in linux systems. coming to the Windows, I am using mingw-64 compiler to compile and link the test file with FMILibrary, but I am getting undefined reference errors. I was able to compile and run it on 32 bit mingw but I need to compile and link it with 64 bit compiled binaries.

My command goes like this:

```
gcc -I <..fmilib\include> -L <..fmilib\lib> -lfmilib -o testfile testfile.c fmivars.c
```

And the following is the result that is getting printed out as a result

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_get_real'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_get_integer'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_get_boolean'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_get_string'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x187): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_set_real'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x1c2): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_set_integer'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x1fd): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_set_boolean'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_set_string'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x27a): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_new_discrete_states'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x2b6): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_collect_model_counts'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_status_to_string'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x37e): undefined reference to `__imp_jm_vsnprintf'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x395): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_status_to_string'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x437): undefined reference to `__imp_jm_vsnprintf'
C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x556): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_get_version'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x575): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_get_types_platform'
C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x594): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_get_number_of_continuous_states'
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x5a8): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_get_number_of_event_indicators'
C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x64a): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_instantiate'
C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x690): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_set_debug_logging'
C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_status_to_string'
C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x6df): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_set_debug_logging'
C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x718): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_setup_experiment'
C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFR53Q1.o:testfile.c:(.text+0x733): undefined reference to `__imp_fmi2_import_enter_initialization_mode'
```

Is there any macro or anything set on the FMILibrary to compile with 64 bit mingw compiler on windows 64 bit? Thanks.

Comment: is fmilib a static lib or a dll ? Also have you checked that your lib or dll is 64 bits ? (you can use Dependency Walker)

Comment: So, I built the library using 64 bit mingw compiler and the path has .dll , .a and .dll.a  in it. But I am trying to link it statically.

Comment: @PilouPili I tried the dependency walker but it says entry point is not bound and is showing red PI. I am not sure what that is supposed to mean. And also I am getting a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the library `libfmilib.x.y.z` provided the missing symbols then on the linker's/compiler's command line move it to the right of the .c-files requiring them

```
gcc -I <..fmilib\include> -L <..fmilib\lib> -o testfile testfile.c fmivars.c -lfmilib
```

Comment: Exactly the same behaviour?

Comment: yes @alk Do you think it might be because the library cannot support 64 bit? Do you think that can be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping me. I finally solved my problem and was able to run the code. I installed dependency walker as suggested by @PilouPili and found out that my application is looking for the library in the same folder(I don't know for some reason) and it was unable to find it. So, I copied all the static and dynamic libraries and I pasted in the folder where my testfile is. Also I changed the command line as suggested by @alk and moved the -lfmilib to the end. And I used the dynamic library instead of static one. But anyways my application runs now. Thank you so much for helping out.